# MVC5 / Ajax / jQuery - Select option box to update data shown in Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In VS, I have an MVC5 app with a relational (SQL Server) database. In one of my Views, I have implemented a jQuery Datatable, populated with data from my database. I also have a Select Option drop down box on the page, with the Options being ID's from the Datatable. I'm wondering how to do an AJAX event handler to display rows that have the ID that was selected from the Select Option drop box.

Datatable code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />

<table id="test-table" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>FACILITY NAME</th>
            <th>DATE</th>
            <th>ASSET NUMBER</th>
            <th>ASSET TYPE</th>
            <th>DESCRIPTION OF MACHINE FUNCTION</th>
            <th>IP ADDRESS</th>
            <th>PHYSICAL LOCATION</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.FacilityName)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Date)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.AssetNo)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.AssetType)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.MachineFunctionDesc)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.IpAddress)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.PhysicalLocation)
                </th>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Select Option box code:

```
<div class="facilitySelection">
    <select name="Facility" class="form-control">
        <option selected disabled>Select a facility...</option>
        @{
            var i = 1;

            foreach (var item in Model)
            {
            <option value="@i">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FacilityName)</option>
                i++;
            }
        }
    </select>
</div>
```

---

This is the code I used to get it working:

First off, realized I didn't need a FacilityName because I was able to derive it from the Facilites table, so now that code looks like:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Facilities.Name)
                </td>
```

then I changed the Select Option code to:

```
<div class="facilitySelection">
    <select id="Facility" name="Facility" class="form-control">
        <option selected disabled>Select a facility...</option>
        @{  
            foreach(var f in ViewBag.Facilities)
            {
                <option value="@f.Id">@f.Name</option>
            }
        }
    </select>
</div>
```

and added the function:

```
$('#Facility').change(function () {
            window.location.href = window.location.pathname + '?facilityId=' + $('#Facility option:selected').val();
        });
```

Comment: There is not datatable plugin implementation, you just have normal table with html only as far as i can see, since you are using razor syntax and view model to populate your table data.

Comment: There are literally a million examples of this, what have you tried? Nobody will give you the answer if you just ask for the code.

Comment: which bit don't you understand? how to make an ajax call, that's easy to google. How to set up datatables, that's easy to google. How to return JSON from MVC, that's easy to google. You don't seem to have broken down the problem into steps and tried to tackle them. have you actually searched and tried to do anything about these requirements? There's nothing novel or unique about what you're trying to do. Research it, make an attempt and then post the relevant code here if you run into a bug you can't fix. We fix bugs with code here, not give full solutions. YMMV on other forums.

Comment: Just seen your solution. Looks like it would work, but it's not ajax as you requested.

Comment: Lol, I figured it out. Edited in my changes. And I didn't even specifically ask for code at all. I don't expect a block of code... I just wanted to know how to approach it... Even in plain English.

Comment: @ADyson Yeah, I realized I could do it like so. Works perfectly for what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: glad you sorted it to your satisfaction. BTW you say you were just looking for the approach to use, but "use an ajax event handler" as you mentioned pretty much _is_ a description of an approach. Much more detail than that and it's going to be code or psuedo-code, it would be hard to answer meaningfully without using that, hence why people are commenting about asking for complete code samples. Also, designs / approaches are arguably opinion-based (lots of ways to skin a cat) and therefore arguably off-topic unfortunately, because anything opinion-based is usually classed as such.

Comment: @ADyson Problem is, I have little experience with Ajax, so I can I figure out how to put a function together like... syntactically, but I kinda need help with the contents of it, so-to-say. I had in mind an answer like, "in the Ajax block you'll need an A and a B, then use your C from your... etc." Lol. Appreciate it, though.